# Regular Expressions: Replacing Portions of a Regex Match

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

Using Vim, Notepad++, or Sublime I'd like to be able to search and replace *portions* of a match. I think this could be done using negative lookahead but I'd like to solicit views from the community.

Say I want to replace incidents of "fall out" with "fallout" in the following examples:

- They are worried about nuclear fall out and radiation.
- There's fall out, and then there's radiation.
- In Nagasaki one of the biggest concerns was fall out.
- One of the best games of the 2000s was "fall out".

A counter example:

- That would fall outside of your purview.

I suppose one obvious pattern to match is:

```
fall out[^a-z]
```

But replacing matches with "fallout" here with this match would have undesirable effects, i.e. the comma, space, period, and trailing quote in the four positive examples would be erased.

How do folks typically handle this, and bonus, how would you preserve upper and lower casing in the match?

Comment: With np++ eg use [`\bfall out\b`](https://regex101.com/r/NlgKPG/1). See [SO documentation about *word boundaries*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1539/word-boundary#t=201707302028316100317) if interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you could probably do what you want with a negative lookahead, I don't think you need one, you could simply use the zero-width atom `\>` (see `:h /\>`) to describe the end of a word.

`\>` means that the previous character is the last of a word (technically the last character inside your buffer-local option `'iskeyword'`).

As for the case issue, you could use capturing groups (see `:h /\(`) to capture `fall` and `out`, so that you can refer to them in the replacement part of your substitutions command.

It would give:

```
:%s/\v\c<(fall)\s+(out)>/\1\2/g
```

Broken down a little:

```
             ┌──────── capture `fall`
             │       ┌ capture `out`
        ┌────┤   ┌───┤
%s/\v\c<(fall)\s+(out)>/\1\2/g
                         │ │
                         │ └─ use the text from the 2nd capturing group (will preserve the case)
                         └─ use the text from the 1st capturing group (will preserve the case)
```

`\s+` describes a sequence of whitespace characters (at least one).
`\c` will make the pattern case-insensitive, and `\v` enables the very magic mode. Without it, you would have to escape several atoms/quantifier in the pattern.

Edit:

Actually, you could simplify the command by just removing the sequence of whitespace:

```
:%s/\v\c<fall\zs\s+\zeout>//g
```

Broken down:

```
%s/\v\c<fall\zs\s+\zeout>//g
            │     │
            │     └─ sets the end of the match
            └─ sets the start of the match
```

This time, you use the atoms `\zs` and `\ze` to set the start and end of the match. See `:h /\zs` and `:h /\ze` for more information.

Comment: Super promising, and detailed explanation, but does this not only apply in Vim?

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber Ah yes, sorry about that. I missed the fact that your question was more general than Vim. Unfortunately, I don't know how the regex engines in the other editors work, so I'm not confident adding more info about them. However, I think that whatever editor you use, the keywords you need to look for, are `capturing group`, `word boundary` and `backreference`. The notation for those constructs may differ from a regex engine to another, but their purpose should be the same.

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber In sublime, for example, I think the parentheses can be used to express a capturing group, like in Vim. `\1` and `\2` can probably be used as backreferences in the replacement part. The only thing that should differ is word boundaries, in sublime it should be `\b` whereas in Vim it's `\<` and `\>`. But the important thing, imho, isn't the constructs themselves but their meaning. The constructs may change, but usually the meaning will stay the same.